# Vertical curl animation like calendar

Tags: ios, animation

I need to implement vertical curl animation as we experience in Table calendars. Please help me by guiding in which direction should I move for the same or please suggest me if their is any example available for the same as till now i have no success to find any example for the same..
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Codrops is a great resource for animations and transitions etc.

This may help with what you're trying to achieve:

You could try this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MoleskineNotebook/